# C# Read SQLite db every 5 seconds (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application where I am reading a SQLite database and painting / populating pins on a map. The database is being updated constantly by a console app.

I need to get the updates and paint new pins based on the updates. I am thinking to read the database every 5 seconds but I have tried a while loop and timers and the screen never gets painted?

What is the best way to run this method every 5 seconds?

```
public void LoadAllPinsFromDataBase(string PathOFDataBase)
            {
            string cs = @"URI=file:C:\JS8Map\radio.db3";
            var con = new SQLiteConnection(cs);
            con.Open();

            {
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con);
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT X, Y, call, grid FROM Radio_Data ";
                SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Addpin(Convert.ToSingle(reader["X"]), Convert.ToSingle(reader["Y"]), Convert.ToString(reader["call"]), Convert.ToString(reader["grid"]));

                }
            }
              
        
            }
```

Comment: I would use the `System.Threading.Timer` class.

Comment: I tried that but the UI hangs and never updates....I'm sure I am missing something but it would seem that I need run this method in a While loop in a backgroundworker?

Answer (score 1):

I used the method DispatcherTimer method shown on this question to resolve my issue.

[WPF UI keeps freezing during while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383773/wpf-ui-keeps-freezing-during-while-loop)